# How to listen in on DOM changes that you make with chrome developer tool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I need to make an application that can detect when I use chrome developer tool to update attributes on a webpage. 
E.g. if I bring up the developer tool, use the elements selector and change the font size of a specific element (see picture). I should be able to have a program running that is notified with what element was updated on the page, and what attributes was changed.

How could that be done?

[image: Chrome developer tool example]

Comment: Did you got solution to this??

Comment: @Tirtha Is the website that needs this feature under your control (made by you)? Could a checksum serve as a possible solution? For instance, the website that is under your control updates checksum whenever it makes changes to DOM. And when you change something using the Developer Console, you just don't update this checksum. Or is something like this considered an invalid workaround for this question?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322012/javascript-listen-for-style-changes-made-in-developer-tools

Comment: @Kumar Your links give no answer to the question. The question is how we can detect updates initated from dev console. The question is not how we can detect DOM updates in general.

Comment: @Wieger The website that needs this feature is mostly not under my control, although I can add extra javascript to the site if needed.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a mutation observor job. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Example http://jsfiddle.net/3y3rpfq5/1/

Sample code:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how I can know that the updates I observe with for example MutationObserver (other options are available) are made from the developer-tool. It might just be a javascript running on the webpage that causes the dom to change?

Comment: @user681814 Not sure what you mean but the fiddle handles the dom change made by button click, i.e. javascript.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: I need to know if the change in the DOM is caused by someone using the developer tool. If the change is caused by anything else, the event should not be acted upon. If I use your fiddle to change font size by clicking on the button, the event should not be acted upon (which is does now). Only if I changed font size with chrome dev tool, it should say "you changed font size with chrome dev tool".