# Javascript listen for style changes made in developer-tools

Tags: javascript, events, developer-tools, web-inspector

Is there a way to detect style changes made only in the developer-tools (inspect element)?

I want to allow to save them if the user is logged in as admin.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that short of using an interval timer to check the entire page for changes all the time.

Comment: It would be very comfortable to use the browser as style editor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the styles of a HTMLElement using `element.style` in JavaScript. So you could probably save the styles on page load, check them again when the user initiates a save and compare -- the difference would be the users changes.

As for detecting them as soon as they happen, you can use `MutationObserver` to get notified of attribute changes on the page. This works for when you add styles to a specific element in the Devtools, but not for editing existing styles and (I think) adding styles to existing selectors. I'm not sure if there is a way to get an event when these change.

Edit: actually, it seems as if checking `element.style` has the same limits as using `MutationObserver`: only styles added for the specific element (that is, styles that show up as inline styles in the DOM) show up. There might be a way to actually access all styles, but I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to be notified when the DOM elements are modified. See the snippet below to see it working.

Note that it does not tell you whether the mutation was triggered by Javascript on your page, or through the developer tools. So, you have the added burden of tracking when your JS changes something and when the user changes something.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('targetDiv');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log("New Mutation:");
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      console.log("Added: " + node.nodeName);
    });

    mutation.removedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      console.log("Removed: " + node.nodeName);
    });
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};
observer.observe(target, config);

function mutate() {
  target.innerHTML += Math.random() + "<br/>"
}
```

```css
#targetDiv {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="targetDiv"></div>

<button id="mutate" onclick="mutate()">Mutate the Div</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the implementation of the mutation observer! Sadly, it looks like it can't handle when from devtools you toggle, add or remove a css property from an already defined rule. It's still very good to check for mutations done directly from the scripts in the page :)